# Saving in Minecraft Pocket for iOS

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft Pocket Edition for iOS doesn't seem to be saving correctly. After resuming the game, up to half an hour of progress from my last session has been reverted. Right now I am just exiting to the title screen before leaving the game.

I also have Minecraft for Android, and it doesn't seem to suffer from this problem.

Does anyone else have this issue, or know what to do in order to make the game save correctly?

EDIT:

On closer inspection, it appears that my inventory is intact, but the game world has reverted to an earlier state. Stranger and stranger...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was indeed a bug. The fix was just announced here: http://www.mojang.com/2013/02/minecraft-pocket-edition-0-6-1-bugfix-is-out/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug on iOS devices in the new version.

On http://www.reddit.com/r/MCPE you can see some identical posts. I think it will be fixed in with the next update.